# Efficient way of removing common elements in ArrayLists?

Tags: java, drawing

I have an `ArrayList<ArrayList<Character>>` that is changed at the end of a computation. I have made a (lazy) method that draws everything in this ArrayList at the end of each computation. The problem is at times I can go multiple iterations without a single change to the ArrayList and it seems highly inefficient to redraw the same thing all the time.

What I thought to do was to take a copy at the end of the iteration, compare it to the one at the end of the next iteration and ONLY draw the differences. A simple way to do this would be to somehow take the difference of the two arraylists, maybe by setting all equal elements to whitespace `' '` (or 0 or anything else, as long as it is clearly distinguishable from the changed elements) and editing my lazy method to only draw non-whitespace. This seems the fastest fix to me but I have no idea how to efficiently implement this. I was wondering if there is any utilities that will take the difference in the above way.

Comment: I am having a little trouble understanding what you are trying to accomplish using ArrayList<ArrayList<Character>>. Why not just use an ArrayList<String> for instance? Could you post some example code?

Comment: Essentially it is 2 dimensional boardgame where pieces are represented by characters.

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, a hash map should do the job a lot better than an array list.

Comment: One would suggest looking into the concept of databinding and replacing your Characters with a representation of the Cell that can fire an event when it changes.

Comment: And you want a simple way to compute the changes between two boards? Are the rows and columns always in the same order?

Comment: Does the board size change while playing the game? If not, why don't you use `char[][]`

Comment: I agree with previous posters that a hashmap or char[][] could be a better fit (and you could use equality operations to check for any changes - though you would still need to iterate over all elements to find the changes).

Comment: @Affe I am really new to Java, building from the ground up as I am learning new concepts. I did think about using my own objects instead of characters and implementing a object.hasChanged() but that I leave for when this optimization is done. I could use a char[][] but would that avoid the problem of optimization I am having now?

Comment: I think I would subclass ArrayList and override the setter methods to keep track of changes in a separate data structure. This is a compromise between using a Cell with change listeners as @Affe suggested (which would occur a memory lot of overhead) and your current use of array lists. I don't think there is a simple way without resorting to using some functional language _magic_, which would just make the code simpler and increase overheads at runtime.

Comment: I really don't think that the standard data structure you use makes much difference (char[][] or ArrayList), since you would always have to iterate over all of the elements whenever there is a change. I had similar problem implementing a chess board, and ended up using multiple representations and keeping them _synched_ (if your board is not huge and you don't plan on creating hundreds of them, I deemed the overhead acceptable). Depending on what I needed to compute (valid moves, check positions etc.), I would use the data structure that would simplify computation most.

Comment: Also be aware of the overhead of the copy operation (for `char[][]` or `ArrayList<ArrayList<Character>>`, which would not be a problem when subclassing ArrayList.

Comment: I will read up on subclassing (haven't yet touched inheritance) and hashmaps and see if I can implement any of them. At the moment I implemented my own comparison scheme which loops over both arrays, that is x2 loops over 2dimensional arrays...not very efficient.